# Missing legend items when using common.legend in ggarrange with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Given a setup like:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr)

size = 20
s = 0.2
d = seq(0,2*pi, length.out=size)
df = data.frame(
  d=d + runif(size)*s,
  a=sin(d) + runif(size)*s,
  b=sin(d-10) + runif(size)*s,
  c=cos(2*d) + runif(size)*s
)
```

when trying to plot the lines with `ggarrange`

```
ggarrange(
  (
    ggplot(df, aes(x=d, palette="Set1"))
    + geom_smooth(aes(y=a, color="A"), se=FALSE)
    + scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999"))
  ),
  (
    ggplot(df, aes(x=d, palette="Set2"))
    + geom_smooth(aes(y=b, color="B"), se=FALSE)
    + geom_smooth(aes(y=c, color="C"), se=FALSE)
  ),
  common.legend=TRUE
)
```

the common legend only shows the items from the first `ggplot` argument, in this case the `A` line. How can I get a common legend to include all of the lines without reformatting the dataframe and using `facet`?

[image: ggarrange line plots]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by defining the `limits` in `scale_color_manual()` in the first plot, along with setting a value for each of your values.

For example, you could add

```
 scale_color_manual(limits = c("A", "B", "C"),
                             values = c("#999999",hcl(c(15, 195), 100, 65)))
```

to the first plot of your example.

```
ggarrange(
    (
        ggplot(df, aes(x=d, palette="Set1"))
        + geom_smooth(aes(y=a, color="A"), se=FALSE)
        + scale_color_manual(limits = c("A", "B", "C"),
                             values = c("#999999",hcl(c(15, 195), 100, 65)))
    ),
    (
        ggplot(df, aes(x=d, palette="Set2"))
        + geom_smooth(aes(y=b, color="B"), se=FALSE)
        + geom_smooth(aes(y=c, color="C"), se=FALSE)
    ),
    common.legend=TRUE
)
```

[image]

Comment: A quick note: I encountered the same problem as @rovyko, and including the "limits" part of `scale_color_manual` proved crucial.